# Countable ordinals in the reals

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to show that for any countable ordinal $\alpha$, there is a subset of $(\mathbb{R},<)$ that has order type $\alpha$. In this post I'm not asking for a solution, but instead for a proof-check. If it's wrong I'll go back to the drawing board.

I tried using induction: assume that every $\beta<\alpha$ admits a subset of $(\mathbb{R},<)$ with order type $\beta$. Since $\alpha$ is assumed countable $\{\beta\in \text{Ord}:\beta<\alpha\}$ is countable, so we can enumerate as $\beta_0,\beta_1\dots$. Then map $f_k:\beta_k\to [k,k+1)\subset \mathbb{R}$ where $f_k$ order preserving and continuous, and $\sup f( \beta_k) = k+1$. Then $\bigcup \beta_k$ is a well-order with order type $\alpha$.

Does this work? If so, is it ok to claim the existence of such $f_k$'s?

Comment: You haven't made it clear how you are using the inductive hypothesis, but the inductive hypothesis does imply the existence of the $f_k$ (more or less). However, your construction gives an order-embedding of the ordinal sum $\beta_0 + \beta_1 + \ldots$ into $\Bbb{R}$ and it is not clear that this ordinal sum has the same order type as $\alpha$. (Less importantly, you are using $\mapsto$ where most people write $\to$; continuity is not relevant; . $\sup \beta_k \not \in \mathrm{dom}\,f_k$ if $\beta_k$ is a limit ordinal, which is why I wrote "more or less" above.)

Comment: You may get something of type *larger* than $\alpha$ with your procedure. (But yes, other than that and minor details, it is essentially fine.)

Comment: Another approach: Show that if $L$ is a countable linear order, then there is an order preserving injection from $L$ into $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: (as a sidenote, $\{\beta \in Ord \ : \ \beta < \alpha\} = \alpha$)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Hm okay. Very new to all of this is still, could you elaborate on how we might get something $>\alpha?$ I can see that all my procedure does is construct something that is larger than all $\beta_k$ but in my head $\alpha$ is the "next/limiting element" so it's not clear to me how this could "skip" $\alpha$.

Comment: Care is needed to avoid using AC. As written, countable choice is used to choose $f_k$ for each $k\lt\omega.$ One might think to avoid that by defining a specific order-preserving $g_\alpha\colon\alpha\to\mathbb{R}$ for each $\alpha\lt\omega_1$ by induction on $\alpha,$ but doing that just as you did still requires AC (worse, because choosing a counting for each $\alpha\lt\omega_1$ requires more than countable choice). I'll give two methods to avoid using AC, both based on what you wrote (you still need to truncate what you get to order type $\alpha,$ as Rob and Andrés have pointed out).

Comment: One way to avoid AC: Fix $\eta\lt\omega_1,$ and fix a counting of $\eta.$ Use that counting of $\eta$ to define a counting of each $\alpha\lt\eta,$ and now define $g_\alpha$ by induction as in the previous comment but just for $\alpha\le\eta,$ using the countings you have for $\alpha\le\eta.$

Comment: A second, slightly different, way to avoid AC: Use your method to construct a function $T$ mapping a subset of ${}^{\omega}\omega_1$ to $\scr{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that for each counting $f$ mapping $\omega$ one-one onto some countable ordinal $\alpha,$ the value $T(f)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of order type $\alpha.$ You can define $T(f)$ by induction on the order type of the range of $f.$

Comment: Alternatively, $$\beta_k\mapsto\sum_{\beta_j\lt\beta_k}2^{-j}$$

Comment: @MitchellSpector Thank you for all that. So first, I'm still a bit confused as to why/how I need to truncate to make sure I am getting order type $\alpha$  (see previous comment directed at Andres). Sorry if that's silly. In your first suggestion, am I just taking the inherited counting from $\eta$ then? I don't *completely* understand how to induct up to $\eta$, in other words I'm not sure what the inductive step should look like. Sorry, pretty confused as you can tell...

Comment: Here's an example where your method gives you something too long. Take $\alpha=\omega+1.$ You produce an ordering of order type $0+1+2+\dots+\omega = \omega+\omega,$ which is greater than $\omega+1.$  (But the only problem with this is that it might longer than $\alpha$ in general, so you can always simply take the initial segment of order type $\alpha.)$

Comment: As for my first suggestion, if you have a counting of some $\eta\lt\omega_1,$ you can get a specific counting of each $\alpha\le\eta$ without using AC by simply taking initial segments of the counting of $\eta.$ What this really means is that you have a function $k$ with domain $\eta+1$ such that for every $\alpha\lt\eta,$ the value $k(\alpha)$ is a counting of $\alpha.$ (Finding a similar $k$ with domain $\omega_1$ requires some use of AC though.)

Comment: Admittedly, this problem on all its variants (embed ordinals into the reals, rationals, with transfinite induction, without it, with choice and without) were discussed previously on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative way of showing that every countable ordinal is order-isomorphic to a subset of the real line (or a subset of $[0,1]$, below).

For finite ordinals this is clear (just take a finite subset of $[0,1]$ with the same number of points).

Now let $\nu=\{\gamma:\gamma<\nu\}$ be an infinite countable ordinal. Fix a bijection $f:\{\gamma:\gamma<\nu\}\to\Bbb N_+$ (where $\Bbb N_+$ denotes the set of all positive integers),  and map each $\gamma<\nu$ to $\psi(\gamma):=\sum\limits_{\delta<\gamma}\frac{1}{2^{f(\delta)}}$.
Note that this maps $\gamma=0$ to $0\in[0,1]$ (i.e. $\psi(0)=0\ $) because
$\sum\limits_{\delta<0}\frac{1}{2^{f(\delta)}}$ is a sum with an empty index set, and by convention it sums up to $0$.
Then, $\psi(1)=\frac{1}{2^{f(0)}}$.
Also
$\psi(2)=\frac{1}{2^{f(0)}}+\frac{1}{2^{f(1)}}\ $, etc.

Clearly if $\beta<\gamma<\nu$ then $\psi(\beta)<\psi(\gamma)$. Indeed, $\psi(\beta)+\frac{1}{2^{f(\beta)}}\le\psi(\gamma)$.

Note also that if $A=\{\psi(\gamma):\gamma<\nu\}$, then $\inf(A)=\min(A)=0$ and $\sup(A)\le1$.
We have $\sup(A)=\max(A)<1$ only when $\nu$ is a successor ordinal (assuming $\nu$ is countably infinite, to begin with).

An alternative definition would be
$\varphi(\gamma):=\sum\limits_{\delta\le\gamma}\frac{1}{2^{f(\delta)}}$.
Then, $\varphi(0)=\frac{1}{2^{f(0)}}$.
Also
$\varphi(1)=\frac{1}{2^{f(0)}}+\frac{1}{2^{f(1)}}\ $, etc.
But, $\psi$ might be a better choice, since $\psi(\gamma)=\sup\limits_{\delta<\gamma}\psi(\delta)$ (in $[0,1]$) exactly when $\gamma$ is limit, i.e.
$\gamma=\sup\limits_{\delta<\gamma}\delta$.

The above is not properly an answer to the original question, as the OP did not ask for a different approach, but only asked  for a verification of the approach presented in the question. I put, nevertheless, this different approach here, for reference. It is slick (though not completely self-contained since it presumes background knowledge of sum of an infinite series), but it is also simple and, I would think, good-to-know.

The notation  $\sum\limits_{\delta<\gamma}\frac{1}{2^{f(\delta)}}$ may need some extra explanation since one usually sees something like
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ rather than $\sum\limits_{\delta<\gamma}$, but the latter is ok too, since all terms are non-negative (so the order in which they appear won't matter) so
$\sum\limits_{\delta<\gamma}\frac{1}{2^{f(\delta)}}$ could be defined as $\sup$ of all possible sums of the form $\frac{1}{2^{f(\delta_1)}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{f(\delta_k)}}$ where $k\ge1$ and $0\le\delta_1<\dots<\delta_k<\gamma$.
This $\sup$ cannot exceed $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}=1$.

Yet another way to explain this, if $g=f^{-1}$ is the inverse bijection, $g:\Bbb N_+\to\{\gamma:\gamma<\nu\}$, then for each $\gamma<\nu$ and all $n\ge1$, one may define
$a_{n,\gamma}= \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{2^n}\ ,\ {\mathrm{ if }}\ g(n)<\gamma\\
      0\ ,\ {\mathrm{ if }}\ \gamma\le g(n)<\nu 
   \end{cases}\ ,$ and then $\sum\limits_{\delta<\gamma}\frac{1}{2^{f(\delta)}}:=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,\gamma}\ $.
Clearly $0\le\psi(\gamma)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,\gamma}< 
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}=1$, for each $\gamma<\nu$. Also, if $\beta<\gamma<\nu$ then $0\le a_{n,\beta}\le a_{n,\gamma}$ for all $n$, and if $m=f(\beta)$ then
$a_{m,\beta}=0<\frac{1}{2^m}=a_{m,\gamma}$
so $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,\beta}<\frac{1}{2^m}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,\beta}\le\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,\gamma}\ .$

Answer (score 0):

The proof is incorrect.  I think you meant to say that $\cup_kS_k$  has order-type $\alpha$ where $S_k$ is the image of $\beta_k$ under $f_k.$ But it's still wrong. For example if $\alpha=\omega + \omega=\omega \cdot 2$ then for some $k',k'',k'''$ we have $\beta_k'=\omega,\; \beta_k''=\omega +1, \beta_k'''=\omega + 2.$ Then each of the  3 intervals $[k',k'+1),\;[k'',k''+1),\;[k''',k'''+1)$ contains a subset  of $\cup_kS_k$ that is order-isomorphic to $\omega,$ so the order-type of $\cup_kS_k$ is at least $\omega \cdot 3.$

For real numbers $a,b$ with $a<b$ let $g_{a,b}:[0,\infty) \to [a,b)$ be an order-isomorphic bijection.

For countable ordinal $\alpha ,$ suppose that for all $b<\alpha$ there exists an order-embedding $f_b$ of $b$ into $[0,1] .$  We show there exists an order-embedding of $\alpha$ into $[0,1].$

(i). If $\alpha =0 $ then $\alpha = \emptyset.$ Let $f_0=\emptyset.$ (Trivial special case.)

(ii). If  $\alpha =c+1,$ let $f_c:c\to [0,1]$ be an order-embedding of $c$ into $[0,1] .$ Define $f_{\alpha} (x)=g_{0,1}(f_c(x))$ for $x <c,$ and $f_{\alpha }(c)=1.$ Then $f_{\alpha }$ is an order-embedding of $\alpha$  into $[0,1].$

(iii). If $0\ne \alpha =\cup \alpha,$ take $\{a_n: n\in \omega\}\subset  \alpha$ with $a_n<a_{n+1}<\alpha$ for  each $n\in \omega,$ and $\cup S=\alpha ,$ and $a_0=0.$

For each $n\in \omega$ the set $a_{n+1}$ \ $a_n$ is order-isomorphic to a (unique) ordinal $b_n,$ with $b_n<\alpha.$  So let $f_n$ be an order-embedding of $a_{n+1}$ \ $a_n$  into $[0,1].$

We have $\cup_{n\in \omega} (a_{n+1}$ \ $a_n)=\alpha$ (because $a_0=0$). For each $x\in \alpha$ there is a unique $n\in \omega$ such that $x\in a_{n+1}$ \ $a_n.$

$$\text {For } x\in a_{n+1} \backslash a_n \text { let }\quad h_{\alpha}(x)=g_{n,n+1}(f_n(x))$$ $$\text {and }\quad f_{\alpha}(x)=g_{0,1}(h_{\alpha}(x)).$$  Then $f_{\alpha}:\alpha\to [0,1]$ is an order-embedding.